# iOS 13 - requesting "When in Use" location permissions prevents me from requesting "Always" later

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, ios13

Our app requests "When in Use" location permissions on startup. Later, we request "Always" location permissions if the user wants to turn on a certain feature. The [WWDC talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/705/?time=1705) about these changes suggests this should be possible:

*if your app requests when in use authorization up front and the user granted it at this prompt, then your app had received when in use authorization with no provisional period and no followup prompt. And it would also have saved up its opportunity to ask for always later when maybe you introduce a killer new feature that really needs it.*

But with iOS 13, when I've first requested "When in Use" permissions, I am seeing the later call to `[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]` be silently discarded with no indication. If I remove the first call to get "When in Use" permissions, requesting Always works fine. Is this behavior expected?

Comment: This is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> be silently discarded with no indication

It is not “silently discarded”. It is silently *granted*. Go ahead and use the feature that requires Always authorization in the background.

Comment: You are correct, I missed this when debugging somehow.

Follow up question: for the same workflow, but the user chooses "Allow Once" in the initial dialog rather than "Allow when in use". I'm seeing, for the subsequent call to requestAlwaysAuthorization, we still silently get the Always permissions. But how will this work when it comes time to actually make use of the permission later? Is it identical to if they had originally chosen "Allow when in use" - in that they'll get a dialog at the time of usage, asking if they want to promote the app to "Always Allow"?

Comment: Once is once. But once is all you need. And next time, you get to ask again.

Comment: I'm not understanding...in this case, I'm seeing the subsequent call to requestAlwaysAuthorization silently grant the permission. So what will happen when it comes time to use the permission, if my app is not running/not in use?

Comment: You already have When In Use authorization, even if only once. As you go into the background you ask for Always authorization and immediately configure your background location monitoring. It works while you’re in the background.

Comment: By the way, all of this is _very_ clearly laid out in the video that you claim to have watched. If you didn't get what it said, it might be good to watch it again.

Comment: I did watch the video, multiple times. For what it's worth, what I am seeing for the "Allow Once" scenario is that the subsequent dialog where the user can grant "Always Allow" never appears. This is misleading from the perspective of the app, because like I said if it calls requestAlwaysAuthorization it gets the callback that it has Always access, but I think my app is taking a different direction so I'm not inclined to investigate this further.

Comment: Well it sounds like you are not doing anything that requires Always authorization. You may be misusing it